# Interval number

Tags: r, sequence

I have the following vector

```
37   15   30   37    4   11   35   37
```

I want to extract intervals of number. The interval starts and ends with the same number. This number appears more than once in the vector.

For example in this case 37: 15, 30 and 4, 11, 35 and 15, 30, 37, 4, 11, 35.

Can this example reproduced to a matrix?

Comment: Is the start and the end always be 37 ?

Comment: @W-B thanks, no i am coding as a number that more than once.

Comment: *"Can this example reproduced to a matrix?"* I'm confused. In the example you give, you're giving what's essentially a list of numbers. How do you want to store that in a matrix? Also, to follow up from W-B's question: How do you determine the start/end number? Is it the number with the highest frequency in your vector?

Comment: Why change the question ...., you should post a new question instead change your older one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding out the start value , using `split` and `cumsum`

```
names(table(v)[table(v)>2])
[1] "37"

split(v[v!=37],cumsum(v==37)[v!=37])
$`1`
[1] 15 30

$`2`
[1]  4 11 35
```